# React Native setup with npm

Tags: npm, react-native, webrtc

I am new to react native and npm. I want to install a demo for my iPhone to try WebRTC. I would like to install this one : https://github.com/oney/RCTWebRTCDemo

However, I am very confused on the steps of setup, what I expected is to do the following steps, but it seems not worked.

1. react-native init RCTWebRTCDemo --version 0.29.0
2. npm install https://github.com/oney/RCTWebRTCDemo.git
3. npm start
4. Connect the iPhone device to Mac
5. Open iOS folder/RCTWebRTCDemo.xcodeproj
6. Run and build in Xcode

Could you please help on the correct steps? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure you have installed **React Native CLI** by `npm install -g react-native-cli`.

Then do following:

1. `git clone https://github.com/oney/RCTWebRTCDemo.git`
2. `cd RCTWebRTCDemo`
3. `npm install`
4. `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`